# python - pandas: output html table with cells that span several rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, pivot-table

Using pandas, how can I get an html table that looks like the attachment?
(where empty cells are numeric values)

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqxI2.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['D','E'],['F','G']])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Y','Z'],['M','N']], names=['X',''])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),len(columns)), index=index, columns=columns)
```

Note that without a more specific question or requirements of your problem, it is difficult to formulate a complete solution that meets your criteria. I would recommend working from the code above and modify to meet your needs, and then ask further specific questions from there.

Comment: That's a good start. But cell 'X' should be followed by a sequence of 'F' 'G' cells, while in your script it is followed by empty cells. Also, for column 'B' cells for rows 'M' and 'N' should be merged.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not a code writing service. I would advise you try to solve this on your own and edit your question with your attempted code.